# How ignore malformed JSON string in Perl

Tags: perl

I have +1000 json files in my folder and when i try to parse data from this +1000 files i get this error after +100 parsing :

```
malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at -e line 1.
```

Please how can ignore this error let command parsing all files.

My command :

```
perl -MJSON::XS -CS -0777ne'
   BEGIN { $j = JSON::XS->new->relaxed(1) }
   s/^\(//;  s/\)\z//;
   CORE::say
      join ",",
         map { join ":", $_->{company}, $_->{time} }
            @{ $j->decode($_)->{Companies} }
' *.json
```

Thanks

Comment: You can try put an [`eval`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) block around the [`decode()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS) call. In this way you can catch the exception

Answer (score 1):

Try use [`eval`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) to catch exception from [`decode()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS) :

```
perl -MJSON::XS -CS -0777ne'
   BEGIN { $j = JSON::XS->new->relaxed(1) }
   s/^\(//;  s/\)\z//;
   eval { $j->decode($_) };
   next if $@;
   CORE::say
      join ",",
         map { join ":", $_->{company}, $_->{time} }
            @{ $j->decode($_)->{Companies} }
' *.json
```

NOTE: If the files are large you can save time (by not decoding the file twice) by storing the decoded variable in the eval block: `eval { $data = $j->decode($_) }` and later use `$data->{Companies}`

Comment: Why would you use two decodes? (And it would be cleaner to use `my $data = eval { $j->decode($_) } or next;`) Also, you should probably output which files are failing.

Answer (score 1):

End of string at position 0 means you passed an empty string (or undef?). Simply check if the file (`$_`) is empty and skip that file.

```
perl -MJSON::XS -CS -0777ne'
   BEGIN { $j = JSON::XS->new->relaxed(1) }
   s/^\(//;  s/\)\z//;
   if (!length($_)) {
      warn("Skipping $ARGV: Empty.\n");
      next;
   }

   CORE::say
      join ",",
         map { join ":", $_->{company}, $_->{time} }
            @{ $j->decode($_)->{Companies} };
' *.json
```

You could take it a step further and skips all files that produce any kind of error (allowing you to fix them or process them manually):

```
perl -MJSON::XS -CS -0777ne'
   BEGIN { $j = JSON::XS->new->relaxed(1) }
   s/^\(//;  s/\)\z//;
   if (!length($_)) {
      warn("Skipping $ARGV: Empty.\n");
      next;
   }

   my $data = eval { $j->decode($_) };
   if (!$data) {
      warn("Skipping $ARGV: $@");
      next;
   }

   CORE::say
      join ",",
         map { join ":", $_->{company}, $_->{time} }
            @{ $data->{Companies} };
' *.json
```